# Typescript keyof object recursively

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to have strong type from key object in Typescript recursively?

Here is example code I have.

```
const test = {
  name: 'abc',
  author: {
    email: 'abc@example.com',
    url: 'http://example.com/'
  }
}

type AType = keyof typeof test
type AObjectKeyToValue = {
  [K in AType]: K  // <- K is just the keys!
}
```

And then I want to create new variable that used type of `AObjectKeyToValue` so I can get power autocomplete from that.

```
const b: AObjectKeyToValue
b.
  ▾▾▾
  name
  author
```

As you can see, I got autocomplete exactly like what I need. But my problem is coming when I need get autocomplete from `author` child.

```
const b: AObjectKeyToValue
b.author.
         ▾▾▾
         // Just string property. Can't find `email` and `url`
```

How to write good types, so I can get `email` and `url` keys when access `b.author.`?

Comment: Cannot say I understood your aim. Are you trying to construct a similar type to `typeof test`?

Comment: Yes, so I can get `email` and `url` keys when access `b.author.`

Comment: Can that be accomplished by just using `typeof test`, like `let b: typeof test;` ?

Comment: Hi @Jokester, that's worked. Thanks. Would you add your answer for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a type from a value (that is determined at compile time), and use it for other values:

```
let b: typeof test = ...;
b.author.email // will be of type "string"
```